# axios get passing parameter to laravel route

Tags: laravel, vue.js, get, routes, axios

I am trying to pass an `id` through `axios.get` in vue.js to laravel route.
my axios code plus parameter are as following,

```
axios.get('http://localhost/laravel_back/public/api/bpaper',{
  params: {
    id:12
}
```

and my laravel route is as follows,

```
Route::get('bpaper/{id}', function($id)
{
return 'Paper '.$id;
});
```

when executing this code i get a 404 error on my browser console. and the request url is,

```
Request URL:http://localhost/laravel_back/public/api/bpaper?id=12
```

I have already given the `access-control allow methods` to allow communication through axios. And the code runs when not providing a parameter. any one know a fix.

Comment: Try this: `axios.get('http://localhost/laravel_back/public/api/bpaper', 
{ params: {'id': 12} })`

Comment: @HirenGohel thats the samething as what i have posted just without the spacing

Comment: I've make quote in id like: `'id'` Have you seen it?

Comment: @HirenGohel sorry my bad. i tried that too but still samething i get a 404 error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerind server-side is `Route::get('bpaper/{id}', function($id) { ...`, the **`id` is part of the path**, not a parameter. Add it to the URL. Do:

```js
var myId = 12;
axios.get('http://localhost/laravel_back/public/api/bpaper/' + myId)
```

Added it to a `myId` variable for clarity, you don't have to do it. Using:

```js
axios.get('http://localhost/laravel_back/public/api/bpaper/12')
```

would work just as well.

Also, if you have access to newer versions of JavaScript, you can profit from **[template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**:

```js
var myId = 12;
axios.get(`http://localhost/laravel_back/public/api/bpaper/${myId}`)
```